# Slide items on click with jquery

Tags: jquery, slider

I've looked everywhere and haven't found something useful.

I have a div containing elements ordered vertically. I need to slide them to display the next items in that div when the user clicks on a next link, and display the previous items when a user clicks on a previous link.

This should display 3 `<li>` and on lcick display the three next, the same with previuos.

```
<div id="container">
   <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
      <li>item4</li>
      <li>item5</li>
      <li>item6</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I need code/sugestions. Don't want to use plugins.

Don't ask what i've tried, just need help, not more questions. If you know how share if don't, don't comment silly things just to get votes.

Comment: Have you looked at the various demos (http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll)? It seems as though you could mix and match a couple of those examples to get started with what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a little example of how it could look like. I hope I understood it correctly.
http://www.jsfiddle.net/BRdCZ/

Comment: Many thanks, this what i was looking for, the only thing is that i was needing to display 3 items at the same time. Three on three.